# Android checkbox cannot use onclick when I set enable=false in xml

Tags: android, checkbox

```
chkSend.setOnClickListener(sendClickListener);

private OnClickListener sendClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }
};
```

I have to set the checkbox disabled,but I need to user the onclick,how can I do?

I found someone said that can work,But I don't know how to use it?

```
public class BtCheckBox extends CheckBox {
    public BtCheckBox(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public BtCheckBox(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public BtCheckBox(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean performClick() {
        return callOnClick();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand. How can a checkbox both be disabled and allow clicks?

Comment: Yeh,I had seen someone said that override the performClick and return callOnClick() can make it.But I don`t know how to use it

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible because when you disable the checkbox, this means it is not clickable.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make your checkBox Unchecked on some condition, you can check that on setOnCheckedChangeListener();

```
checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
               @Override
               public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {
                     if(isChecked)
                     {
                        checkBox.setChecked(false);
                     }
               }
           });
```